# Using SCSF with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, scsf

I am now using SCSF 2008 April version with visual studio 2008. Now i want to convert my whole solution in visual studio 2010. So what should i do abput SCSF?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about SCSF, there is a 2010 version of it that is compatible with VS 2010.

You can download/find out more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709809.aspx